# Android custom video camera minimum duration

Tags: android, android-camera

i'm developing android application which used camera feature. it can capture video fragment. But i found some problem with fragments < 1sec and didn't find any information about minimal video duration. Who knows something about it? What's minimal duration for video?

Answer (score 0):

for record video limited video you can use following code, in this case video will recorded of 15 seconds

int VIDEORECORD=1;

int DURATION=15 /* time given IN seconds */

Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE); cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_DURATION_LIMIT,DURATION); startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, VIDEORECORD);

Comment: yes, i know. But i use MediaRecorder for custom video application. it's not native android camera.